# Spring @Transactional annotation is not rollback when second table insertion have exception

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I want to insert two different table consecutively in a service class , i am using Spring JDBCTemplate.My code are.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class,propagation= Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public boolean insertRestorent(User user) throws GenericException {
    logger.println(IMessage.INFO, new StringBuilder(CLASS_NAME).append("::insertRestorent() restorent registration start"));

        user.setUserType(USER_TYPE.RESTORENT.ID);
        User checkUser = userDao.checkUserByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (checkUser != null) {
            GenericException exception = new GenericException();
            exception.setMessage("Shop already registered!!");
            throw exception;
        }
        long getuserUid=userDao.insertUser(user);


        long retoId= restorentdao.insertRestorent(user, getuserUid);

    return false;
}
```

My transactionManager code is

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

My problem is when userDao.insertUser(user); is successful but if there is any exception in restorentdao.insertRestorent(user, getuserUid); then fist  user table is not rollback.
Exceptions are.

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MyDelivery] in context with path [/MyDelivery] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; Field 'shop_description' doesn't have a default value; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Field 'shop_description' doesn't have a default value] with root cause
>   java.sql.SQLException: Field 'shop_description' doesn't have a default value

userDao insert method is.

```
    public long insertUser(User user) {

    logger.println(IMessage.INFO, new StringBuilder(CLASS_NAME).append("::insertUser()"));
    final String query = "INSERT INTO user(user_type,email,mobile_no,password,name,status,created_on)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,now());";
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    getJdbcTemplate().update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            int i = 1;
            ps.setLong(i++, user.getUserType());
            ps.setString(i++, user.getEmail());
            ps.setString(i++, user.getMobileNo());
            ps.setString(i++, user.getPassword());
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getName())) {
                ps.setString(i++, user.getName());
            } else {
                ps.setString(i++, null);
            }

            ps.setInt(i++, STATUS.INACTIVE.ID);

            return ps;
        }
    }, keyHolder);
    user.setUserId(keyHolder.getKey().longValue());

    return keyHolder.getKey().longValue();
}
```

Comment: Show `userDao` `insertUser` method too please.

Comment: I have Edited question by adding userDao insertUser method.

Comment: @john16384 how can i fix checked Exception in Spring transactional.